# C: const or define? What's the difference and why the second report an error?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, constants, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 15 //line that give problems

int linearSearch(int v[], int MAX, int valore);

int main()
{
    int ris, valore, v[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,12,1,1,1,1,1};
    scanf("%d", &valore);
    ris = linearSearch(v, MAX, valore);
    printf("%d", ris);
    return 0;
}

int linearSearch(int v[], int MAX, int valore)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        if(valore==v[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;    
}
```

Why this code report me error while compiling? And why it run correctly if I substitute the preprocessor directive with

```
const int MAX = 15;
```

Comment: Your parameter `int MAX,` - think about what that does when the preprocessor substitutes `MAX` with `15`... `int 15` ??

Comment: You don't even need the middle parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are (mostly) simple textual substitutions so:

```
#define MAX 15 //line that give problems
int linearSearch(int v[], int MAX, int valore);
```

will be preprocessed to:

```
int linearSearch(int v[], int 15, int valore);
                              ^
```

and of course you cannot have a numerical value for an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

In the function declaration

```
int linearSearch(int v[], int MAX, int valore);
```

and its definition

```
int linearSearch(int v[], int MAX, int valore)
{
   //...
}
```

identifier `MAX` denotes a variable name.

However due to the macro-definition

```
#define MAX 15
```

the function declaration and definition look like

```
int linearSearch(int v[], int 15, int valore);

int linearSearch(int v[], int 15, int valore)
{
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            if(valore==v[i])
                return i;
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

because the preprocessor makes substitutions of all `MAX` for 15 before the program compilation.

Macto definitions do not have scopes. Thus it is better to use a usual constant declaration. If you would write

```
const int MAX = 15;
```

then this name `MAX` and name `MAX` in the function declaration

```
int linearSearch(int v[], int MAX, int valore);
```

had different scopes and the code would be compiled successfully.

Take into account that when you define a constant you specify its type that is not necessary the same type as the type of the corresponding integer literal. For example you could define the constant like

```
const unsigned int MAX = 15;
```

Now compare the result of the following condition when on the one hand there is used the constant defined above and on the other hand the macro definition.

```
const unsigned int MAX = 15;

if ( MAX > -1 ) puts( "MAX is greater than -1" );
else puts( "MAX is less than -1" );
```

and

```
#define MAX 15

if ( MAX > -1 ) puts( "MAX is greater than -1" );
else puts( "MAX is less than -1" );
```